# Apportioning the Holy Land by family

Tags: eretz-yisrael, shevatim-12-tribes, real-estate

The Torah tells us how the Promised Land was apportioned by Tribe of Israel.  But within each tribe, how was the land apportioned by family?  On what basis?  Anything in the Sources?

Comment: There are general rules of inheritance. Once we know the family, why wouldn't we just apply those?

Comment: Inheritance from whom?

Comment: The head of the family. IE. Binyamin had 10 sons. His portion gets split into 11 based on the standard rules of inheritance (counting the double for Bechor) and each of the sons receive their portion.

Comment: @Salmononius2 I think the OP is asking how it was decided which family got which portion

Comment: @DonielF -- Yes; both actually, but geographic assignment is hardest.

Comment: I recall asking a preliminary question - was ALL the land divided or not? If yes, you can divide it proportionally (based on its value) between all the 600K of those who left Egypt(!) (20,770 sq km or 8,019 sq mi, or 36 dunams each family). If not, pick a value and divide equally, say 10 sq miles each (but how didn't they grab additional lands then?)